# CI constructor is failing to load

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-ec2, codeigniter-2

I have written a core controller in application/core--MY_Controller.php:

```
class MY_ProtectedController extends CI_Controller{
   public function __construct(){
    echo("I luv bd1"); //This echo's
    parent::__construct();
    echo("I luv bd2"); //this one even couldn't reached to
    $this->CI=& get_instance();     
    $this->CI->load->library('permission');
    $this->CI->load->library('authentication');
    $this->CI->load->model('commonmodel');
    $this->CI->load->model('admin/usermodel');
    $this->CI->load->library('imagelib');
    $this->CI->load->library('facebook');       
  }
```

As you could see the first echo is echoed but the second cant get reached because parent::__construct calls CI_Controllers's __construct which fails somewhere in method resolution order(successive calls to other methods in it---I guess). If I keep debugging I think it's gonna take me the whole day excepting I have already wasted two days behind this.

**FYI: I'm on EC2 VPS. installed php5.4*,apache2.4*,mysql5.5* CI:2.1.3, php.ini:display_errors=On, 
CI: error_reporting(E_ALL) 
[But CI's error log is not being written may be for the same reason. I have given log folder 755 perm.]
More Debug: Calling controllers without inheriting from MY_protected also results in the same.
In the matter of course: autoload,library load, view load,helper load ALL ARE FAILING.**

**Please Help!**

Comment: check the apache error log file

Comment: @Sundar Hey bro. Ithink we've alredy talked about this in another question yesterday. I told u bro I checked it. It giving me nothing. Anyway I'm checking it as from  ~>tail -n 300 error_log.txt and it gives me last 300 lines where nothing says that the constructo is having a trouble. But I discovered it through debuging line by line.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing a fresh copy of [codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter), i.e. [Download Codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/download) and Paste only the files you have changed or added.

For instance you most likely added new files to the controllers folder, so move your work in to the, fresh install of codeigniter's, controllers folder. do this for all you work..

I know this is not a proper solution, but at least if you do it this way you can continue working. I can not see with the info you provided, why it would not run anything after  `parent::__construct();` or even run that line.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please see [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21931570/how-do-i-get-php-mysql-for-php-5-4-23-while-its-conflicting-with-php-common-5-3)